# how to feed a non R file in a function within a package?

Tags: r, function, package

I am creating a package by including all functions that I use to generate a report. I use a template for report. I am wondering whether I can include the template (a word doc file) inside a folder in the package & make the function use it? More specifically, I couldn't figure out how I need to specify the filepath of the doc file inside function. Any help?

> library(ReporteRs)
>   if(!exists("temp")) temp = docx(title> ="Summary", template="C:\Users\User\a_template.docx")

Syntax above is the current setup.

Comment: put it somewhere within `inst` and use `system.file(...,package="mypackage")` to find it ?

Comment: I am trying to understand how it would find the file `a_template.docx`. Instead of `...`, I need to specify `a_template.docx`?

Comment: feel free to write up/answer your own question below ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @BenBolker's suggestion, I was able to fix my syntax.

```
if(!exists("temp")) 
    temp <- docx(title = "Summary",
         template=system.file("a_template.docx", package="my.package"))
```